# Sort array of pair by frequency of occurrence in C/C++

Tags: arrays, string, sorting, frequency

Here I have two arrays, one string, and one int:

```
S[]={"abc","abc","aa","a","aa","abc"}
A[]={  3,    2,   4,   5,  6,   7 }
```

Each element in S[] is linked with corresponding element in A[] (Ex: "abc"-3, "abc"-2, and so on)

I want to sort these arrays by the frequency of occurrence of S[i], for example:

```
Sorted arrays: S[]={"abc","abc","abc","aa","aa","a"}
               A[]={ 2,    3,    7,    4,   6,   5 }
```

So the S[] is sorted by the frequency of occurrence of s[i], and if two elements have the same frequency, the "smaller" element in the alphabet comes first.

And the corresponding a[] element should be sorted increasingly if two s[] elements are the same.

What should I use to sort them, pair or using map, because I tried to use these but I still got stuck.

Any idea with the example code would be appreciated.

Comment: First, order both arrays according to the sort order of `A`. Then, use a **stable** sorting algorithm to sort the strings in `S`. Stable sorting will ensure that strings with a lower corresponding value in `A` will appear before strings with higher values.

Comment: @beaker yeah, but I want sort S[] by frequency, and I faced the problem when try to count the number of ocurrence of the element, I do not know how to count and store it to a seperated vector or link with pair or map.

Answer (score 0):

```
using namespace std
struct ds_t{
    string s;
    vector<int>i;
    ds_t(string ts, int value){
        s = ts;
        i.push_back(value);
    }    
};

int main()
{
    char* s[] = {"abc","abc","aa","a","aa","abc"};
    int   A[] = {3,2,4,5,6,7};
    map<string, ds_t> mVar;
    map<string, ds_t>::iterator itr;

    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(s)/sizeof(char*) ; i++)
    {
        itr = mVar.find(s[i]);
        if(itr == mVar.end())
        {
            struct ds_t vDs(s[i],A[i]);
            mVar.insert(make_pair(s[i], vDs));
        }
        else
        {
            itr->second.i.push_back(A[i]);
            std::sort(itr->second.i.begin(), itr->second.i.end());
        }
    }

    map<string, ds_t>::reverse_iterator ritr;
    for(ritr = mVar.rbegin() ; ritr != mVar.rend(); ++ritr)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<ritr->second.i.size();i++)
        {
            printf("%s %d\n",ritr->first.c_str(),ritr->second.i[i]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I'd do this in two steps. First I'd count up the frequencies (and that could use `std::map` or `std::unordered_map`. Then I'd do the sorting, using that as the primary key and the strings and associated number as secondary and tertiary keys.

```
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

using T = std::pair<std::string, int>;

namespace std {
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, T const &t) {
    return os << t.first << ", " << t.second;
}
}

int main() {

    std::vector<T> inputs {
        { "abc", 3 }, {"abc", 2}, { "aa", 4}, {"a", 5}, { "aa", 6 }, { "abc", 7 }
    };

    std::unordered_map<std::string, int> counts;

    // first count the frequencies:
    for (auto const & i : inputs)
        ++counts[i.first];

    // order by freq desc, first asc, num asc
    std::sort(inputs.begin(), inputs.end(),
        [&](T const& a, T const& b) {
            if (counts[b.first] < counts[a.first])
                return true;
            if (counts[a.first] < counts[b.first])
                return false;
            if (a.first < b.first)
                return true;
            if (b.first < a.first)
                return false;
            return a.second < b.second;
        });

    // Show the result:
    std::copy(inputs.begin(), inputs.end(), std::ostream_iterator<T>(std::cout, "\n"));
}
```